# What should be used in ColdFusion to map to SOAP type tns:ArrayOfString?

Tags: web-services, soap, coldfusion

If one `cfinvoke` a SOAP web service with param type sets to `tns:ArrayOfString`, one will get:

> Cannot perform web service invocation Hello. The fault returned when
>   invoking the web service operation is:
>   ''java.lang.IlligalArgumentException: argument type mismatch

How to invoke a web service with type `tns:ArrayOfString`?

According to http://forums.adobe.com/message/4337438

This works:

```
<cfscript>
     root = structnew();
     text = arraynew(1);
     text[1] = "Hello";
     text[2] = "world";
     root.string=text;
</cfscript>

<cfinvoke method="Hello"
  webservice="http://localhost/Service1.asmx?wsdl"
  returnvariable="response">
     <cfinvokeargument name="array" value=#root#/>
</cfinvoke>
```

now the question is, why does this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like I mentioned in the thread you referenced, there is [no direct mapping](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-78b2.html) of `ArrayOfString`. So it is essentially treated as a structure, just like any other complex type. If you look at the wsdl, `ArrayOfString` contains a single key named `string`, whose value is an array of `type="s:string"`:

```
<s:complexType name="ArrayOfString">
   <s:sequence>
     <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" 
           name="string" nillable="true" type="s:string" /> 
   </s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
```

So the CF code works because it creates a structure with the correct key name (`string`) and value type (array of strings).

```
    root.string = [ arrayOfStrings ];
```