# Method cannot be found when invoking Webservice API

Tags: web-services, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

While invoking the [Webservice API](http://www.argusmedia.com/ArgusWSVSTO/ArgusOnline.asmx) for the `GetTablesBin` method, I'm getting the error `Web service operation GetTablesBin with parameters cannot be found.`

Webservice Calling code

```
<cfinvoke  
    webservice="http://www.argusmedia.com/ArgusWSVSTO/ArgusOnline.asmx?wsdl"
    method="GetTablesBin" 
    returnvariable="binResponse"> 
    <cfinvokeargument name="authToken" value="#AuthToken#"/>
    <cfinvokeargument name="tableNames" value="#tablename#"/>
 </cfinvoke>
```

I can see the method running fine using the `SOAPUI` client.

While digging further, found the method class to be missing in the Coldfusion stubs folder as well.

[image: Stubs folder screenshot for the API classes]

Any pointers would be really helpful?

Comment: Did you already refresh the wsdl in CFIDE/administrator? (Data & Services -> Web Services)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Web service operation GetTablesBin **with parameters**
>   {...} cannot be found.

Notice it says "with parameters"? Subtle difference, but it either means a) the method does not exist at all OR b) it *does* exist, but is receiving the wrong number or type of arguments. In this case the problem is "b)".

When troubleshooting web service issues, it is often helpful to create an instance of the web service, then dump that object to see which arguments the method requires. According to CF11, the "GetTablesBin" method expects two arguments: a `String` and an `ArrayOfString`. However, the current code passes in two `String`'s. Hence the error.

**Code:**

```
<!--- Add {refreshWSDL=false} if needed --->
<cfset ws = createObject("webservice"
              , "http://www.argusmedia.com/ArgusWSVSTO/ArgusOnline.asmx?wsdl")>
<cfset writeDump(ws)>
```

**Dump:**

[image: Web Service - GetTablesBin Method]

An `ArrayOfString` is a [slightly strange beast](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13943192/104223):

> ... there is no direct mapping of `ArrayOfString`. So it is essentially
>   treated as a structure, just like any other complex type. If you look
>   at the wsdl, ArrayOfString contains a single key named `string`, whose
>   value is an array of `type="s:string"`:

To resolve the error, simply create a structure with the proper key and pass it into the cfinvoke call. (Though personally I prefer `createObject()` which is a little less bulky IMO)

```
<cfset arrayOfStrings = ["tableName1","tableName2"] />
<cfset tableNames.string = arrayOfStrings  />

<cfinvoke ....>
    <cfinvokeargument name="authToken" value="#AuthToken#"/>
    <cfinvokeargument name="tableNames" value="#tableNames#"/>
</cfinvoke>
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks so much. I had to remove the square brackets in the line of code for it to work `<cfset tablenames.string = arrayofstrings>`.

Comment: @GauravS - Oops, that was a typo. Good catch. I will update the answer with the fix.